# Communication failure during handshake. Is there a MySQL server running on localhost:3306

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i am using below code

```
try {
            Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb","root","root"); // cust is the DSN Name
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception "+e);
        }
```

got this exception during run time...

tried netstat -a in command prompt to check if mysql is running on port 3306 below is the trace...

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    user:epmap             user:0                 LISTENING
TCP    user:microsoft-ds      user:0                 LISTENING
TCP    user:3306              user:0                 LISTENING

Answer (score 0):

Well, googling your problem i have come to [this solution](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,6448,77511#msg-77511):

Try reseting your user password executing the next statement at your mysql command line client:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = OLD_PASSWORD('root');
```

As it seems it kind of changes the authentication method at the mysql server.

Let me know if this have worked.

Other option is to check the compatibility between the version of your MySQL database and the MySQL JDBC driver you are using.